how to design a nested dictionary input data with pydantic model?
i have a fast api and i'm trying to model my input data, as shown below. i want to define the data class such that , the colleges is a list , but optional , a person may or may not have college experience and within this list, there is a classes list which is optional. i have included a optional keyword , such that even if the input is missing these values , the call to my api doesn't fail. is this the right way to design my classes . also , is there a better/short way to design my classes in pydantic for nested model classes ? person -> colleges , then colleges have classes , a nested structure. can one define entire structure in a single class vs having to define three classes?
{
    'name': 'john',
    'Colleges': [
        {
            'name': 'Harvard',
            ...
            'Classes': [
               {
                   'level': 'graduate',
                   'grade': 'A'
               }, 
               {
                    'level': 'graduate',
                    'grade': 'B'
               }
            ]
        }
    
    ]
    
}

# Import required modules
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List

# Create a FastAPI app instance
app = FastAPI()

class Class(BaseModel):
     level: str
     grade: int

class College(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    Classes: optional[List[Class]]= None
    

class Person(BaseModel):
    
    name: str
    description: str
    Colleges: Optional[List[College]] = None


@app.post("/create/", response_model=dict)
def create(person: Person):
    //do somethign 
    return {'message': 'success'}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)


You can define entire structure in a single class, like colleges: Optional[list], then you don't need to define College or Classes class, but I think define all classes of your input would be more clear. By the way, you can import keyword Optional from typing

Don't use Optional[list], but do it the way you've done. That works fine. Two suggestions: use the same capitalization for all your keys, so colleges, not Colleges, and classes, not Classes. This makes it more consistent with your other keys. If you're on Python 3.10 or later you don't need Optional, but you can instead say that the parameter can be None by typing it as having two possible types: colleges: List[College] | None = None. Whether this is more readable will be up to you (and if you're not on 3.10 or later it won't work).

And just to add, the reason for not using Optional[list] is that you lose all the relevant information in your swagger documentation and no built-in validation of the submitted data - so be specific with what you expect and you'll get all that for free.

Your implementation is mostly correct. While, nesting directly in one class may be possible, but it's less readable and harder to manage as your structure grows.
One-Class Nested Approach
It's not recommended for readability and maintainability. However, here's how it could be done:
class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    colleges: Optional[List[dict]] = None

This sacrifices the benefit of strong type-checking and validation provided by Pydantic's nested models. If you need to access nested properties in your API logic, you lose auto-completion and validation benefits.
However, there are a few corrections and improvements that can make the code cleaner and more concise:
Improved version of your code
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Optional

# Create a FastAPI app instance
app = FastAPI()

# Define nested Pydantic models
class Class(BaseModel):
    level: str
    grade: str  # Grade should be a string (e.g., 'A', 'B')

class College(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    classes: Optional[List[Class]] = None  # Use lowercase for JSON-friendly field names

class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    colleges: Optional[List[College]] = None  # Use lowercase for JSON-friendly field names

@app.post("/create/", response_model=dict)
def create(person: Person):
    # Do something with the input
    return {'message': 'success'}

Changes in your code

JSON-friendly field names use lowercase (classes, colleges) instead of Classes, Colleges.
Changed optional[List[Class]] to Optional[List[Class]]. (typo in optional)
Grade might better fit as a str instead of int ('A', 'B').
Optional field description are handled properly with Optional.

